# Conical viewshed query

Tags: qgis-processing, viewshed

I have a project relating to an analysis of a national geodetic network. The data I am working with is a 0.15m pixel size dsm as well as a vector file denoting each station forming part of the existing network. 
I need to create a viewshed on each point. However the area of interest is an angle of 10 degrees above the horizontal. So essentially my query has to be similar to a viewshed but taking into consideration 80 degrees from nadir. The area of interest above each station will form a cone which will represent the needed clear view for satellite visibility from a gnss antenna.

Any idea of how to go about it in qgis

Comment: I think this would be 'visibility analysis', so wondering if any of these help? https://www.giscourse.com/how-to-create-a-visibility-analysis-with-qgis/ or https://blog.thinkwhere.com/2016/08/25/viewsheds-and-visibility-analysis-in-qgis/